# How to assign a single count to groups of adjacent identical values in R

Tags: r, counting

I have a column that contains binary values indicating the presence (1) or absence (0) of an event. Based on this column I want to create a new column containing a continuous count that assigns a single count to groups of adjacent events.

```
event <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)

count<- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,0)

df <- data.frame(event, count)
```

The desired count should look like this:

```
event   count
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   1
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   3
1   3
0   0
0   0
```

Any suggestions how to get there are much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, the following checks whether there is a `1` following a `0` and takes the cumulative sum of that. Then, the result is multiplied by `event` such that the zeros are maintained.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(count_2 = event * cumsum(event == 1 & lag(event, default = 0) == 0))
```

gives

```
   event count count_2
1      0     0       0
2      0     0       0
3      0     0       0
4      1     1       1
5      0     0       0
6      0     0       0
7      0     0       0
8      1     2       2
9      1     2       2
10     1     2       2
11     1     2       2
12     1     2       2
13     0     0       0
14     0     0       0
15     0     0       0
16     0     0       0
17     0     0       0
18     0     0       0
19     1     3       3
20     1     3       3
21     0     0       0
22     0     0       0
```

A base-R variant:

```
df$count_2 <- df$event * cumsum(c(0, diff(df$event)==1))
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do it with mutate() previously but failed. Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Using `rle` in base R :

```
df$count1 <- with(df, event * with(rle(event == 1),rep(cumsum(values), lengths)))
df

#   event count count1
#1      0     0      0
#2      0     0      0
#3      0     0      0
#4      1     1      1
#5      0     0      0
#6      0     0      0
#7      0     0      0
#8      1     2      2
#9      1     2      2
#10     1     2      2
#11     1     2      2
#12     1     2      2
#13     0     0      0
#14     0     0      0
#15     0     0      0
#16     0     0      0
#17     0     0      0
#18     0     0      0
#19     1     3      3
#20     1     3      3
#21     0     0      0
#22     0     0      0
```